# How to get "Friends who like/play games" list (similar to Farmville 2)

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a Facebook app, and I'm trying to get a friends list similar to Farmville 2.

They have a "friends who like games" list. My first thought is, I can get a list of all friends, then for each friend, see if they like any pages with type == "GAMES/TOYS". But ideally, I would like to get the list in one query (not by making one graph API or FQL request per friend).

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: wonder why this is migrated to gamedev. this is purely a fb api question, should remain here or migrate to facebook.se

Comment: This is migrated FROM gamedev